# How to capture FormData on a post request using Node/Multer

Tags: node.js, angular, express, multer

I basically need to save a formData on a mongodb schema, using nodejs + 
express as backend, and multer as middleware, this formData consist on a string and a blob

**i need to capture the blob and the string and somehow save on the db, but right now i cant even capture on my backend**

[formData appends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1JZ5.png)

my req.body and my req.files appear as undefined

thanks in advance

Post Service on angular

```
addPost(message, blob): Observable<any> {
    var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append('id', message);
    fd.append('invoiceFile', blob);

    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      Accept: 'multipart/form-data'
    });

    let options = {
      headers: httpHeaders
    };

    return this.http.post(`${addPost}`, fd, options);
  }
```

My node server.js

```
  const express = require('express');
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
  // const morgan = require('morgan');
  const app = express();
  const cors = require('cors');
  var fs = require('fs');

  const dbConfig = require('./config/env');

  app.options('*', cors());
  app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));

   app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  next();
});

   app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
   app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));

   app.use(logger('dev'));

   mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
   mongoose.connect(
  dbConfig.url,
  { useNewUrlParser: true }
);

  const auth = require('./routes/authRoutes');
  const posts = require('./routes/postRoutes');
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(auth);
  app.use(posts);

 app.listen(3000, () => {
     console.log('Runnning on port 3000');
});
```

My route

```
router.post('/api/post/add-post', upload.any(), function(req, res) {

  console.log(req.body); // appear as undefined
  console.log(req.file); // appear as undefined
  res.status(204).end();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if while sending your form Data is blank or not .
It should be in jpg/jpeg or the format you want to send. I had my form data blank so i realized i had to send file.name which is "image.jpg" and not the entire file details
send a snapshot below see if this helps
[image]